# Multiplication and setInterval javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making an incremental game and I have what I want working in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JohnTh/yma43rco/3/) but I can't for the life of me get it to work on my actual website. [Here's](https://gyazo.com/616cf2c2fea889f51d580d8697844258) what happens on my website.

Here's my code for working this out:

```
SetInterval(function() {
  for(var outer in user.upgrades)
  {
    for(var inner in user.upgrades[outer])
    {
      loadedUser.upgrades[outer][inner].cost = Math.floor(user.upgrades[outer][inner].cost * Math.pow(user.upgrades[outer][inner].scale, loadedUser.upgrades[outer][inner].owned));
    }
  }
}, 10);
```

The loadedUser object and user object:

```
var costScaling = 1.15;
const user = {
  "name": "",
  "stats": {
    "click": 1,
    "level": 1,
    "xp": 0,
    "melons": 0,
    "mps": 0,
  },
  "upgrades": {
    "melons": {
      "mash": {
        "name": "Mash - 1MPS",
        "cost": 50,
        "value": 1,
        "owned": 0,
        "scale": costScaling
      }
```

The loadedUser would be the same as this however in the upgrades.melons in the amount but there would be how many they own.

So, my issue is as you can see in the gyazo is that it turns into a really big number very quickly however on the JSFiddle is exactly what I want and I'm struggling to get it work locally, on the console is the value of user.upgrades which shouldn't even change. If you need anymore code just ask.

Comment: Make sure you place your script just before the closing `</body>` tag or else wrap your code in `window.onload = function () { // your code };`. This is to allow the DOM to be ready before your code runs.

Comment: @trincot Is having it after the last `</body>` tag okay?

Comment: That will also work, although not strictly allowed by the HTML standard. But browsers play nice...